# How to check if iPhone is jailbroken or not, from terminal on a Mac?

Tags: iphone, ios, macos, jailbreak, detect

I would like to execute some scripts on my Mac, to which an iOS device is connected. The intent of the script would be to identify whether the connected device is jailbroken or not. Would be great if you could suggest the solution using bash or py.

Answer (score 3):

You can attempt to SSH into it via the iPhone's connection program "usbmux" (to forward the wired data connection to a port on your computer).  There is a script, as well as instructions on this [GitHub page](https://github.com/rcg4u/iphonessh)

Comment: Not all jailbreak mechanism enables ssh on the device. This would fail to detect such jailbroken devices.

Comment: Yes, you are right @ocelot .  However, it is very common.  On those without an SSH mechanism I think it would be outright impossible anyway... Furthermore, the page offers a way to enable SSH remotely from the Mac using iFuse.

Answer (score 1):

Try this https://github.com/libimobiledevice/ifuse You can check if device allows you to access it's root folder. If you can access root folder then it's definitely jailbroken.

It's true that jailbreak doesn't necessarily mean you can access it's entire filesystem but all modern jailbreak solutions install AFC2 service which allows full filesystem access.

Comment: Note that starting from iOS 7.1 jailbroken devices don't have AFC2 installed by default.